# google-closure compiler advanced optimization is munging navigator.battery.level causing TypeError

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, navigator

I'm using ClojureScript to retrieve battery levels with:

```
 navigator.battery.level
```

Which works fine when using the simple and whitespace optimization. But when using advanced optimization mode the above gets turned into:

```
navigator.hd.rd
```

And causes a TypeError as navigator.hd is undefined.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Fixed thanks to the answer below. Though in ClosureScript I would have to do some nasty, nested, agets... So I came up with this:

```
(defn jget [jobject & props]    
(loop [obj jobject 
       p (map name props)]
    (if (not (empty? p))            
        (let [prop (aget obj (first p))]
            (recur prop (rest p)))
    obj)))
```

then called it like so:

```
(jget js/navigator :battery :level)
```

If there are already tools out there for this could some one please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other solution is to write an `externs` file, which is a JavaScript file that contains references to all the objects and methods whose names you want to preserve. In this case, the JS file would look something like this:

```
//resources/externs/navigator.js
navigator = {}
navigator.battery = {}
navigator.battery.level = function(){};
```

And you'd refer to it in your ClojureScript complier options as:

```
:externs ["resources/externs/navigator.js"]
```

Like Sirko's proposed solution, this will prevent advanced-mode compilation from munging the `navigator.battery.level` name.

Comment: Thanks levland, If I want to automate the generation of extern files is it safe to say that given the string: "<1>.<2>.<3>" e.g: "navigator.battery.level" That the filename should = <1>, <1> to <1>.<n-1> should always be assigned = {}, and <1>.<..>.<n> should always be assigned = function(){}.

Comment: @jdoig Auto generating an extern is not near that easy in general. The above extern doesn't contain any type information or nested types.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 navigator['battery']['level']
```

this will preserve the naming.

The closure compiler most often will rename variables of the dot notation (like `navigator.battery`), but retain those, he knows or that use bracket notation (like navigator['battery']).

Comment: Correct. Closure-compiler does not currently have externs for the Battery Status API.